# CSRF Exempt Failure - APIView csrf django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code:

The problem is when I try to access user-login/ I get an error:
"CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set."

What can I do?

I am using the django rest framework.

```
urls.py:

url(r'^user-login/$', 
    csrf_exempt(LoginView.as_view()),
    name='user-login'),

views.py:

class LoginView(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
def get(self, request, format=None):
    startups = Startup.objects.all()
    serializer = StartupSerializer(startups, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    profile = request.POST

    if ('user_name' not in profile or 'email_address' not in profile or 'oauth_secret' not in profile):
        return Response(
            {'error': 'No data'},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    username = 'l' + profile['user_name']
    email_address = profile['email_address']
    oauth_secret = profile['oauth_secret']
    password = oauth_secret
```

Answer (score 14):

I assume you use the django rest framework [SessionBackend](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#sessionauthentication). This backend does a [implicit CSRF check](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L119)

You can avoid this by:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class UnsafeSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        http_request = request._request
        user = getattr(http_request, 'user', None)

        if not user or not user.is_active:
           return None

        return (user, None)
```

And set this as [authentication_classes](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#setting-the-authentication-scheme) in your View

```
class UnsafeLogin(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,) #maybe not needed in your case
    authentication_classes = (UnsafeSessionAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        username = request.DATA.get("u");
        password = request.DATA.get("p");

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
           login(request, user)

        return redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 13):

Actually, better way to disable csrf check inside SessionAuthentication is:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication as OriginalSessionAuthentication

class SessionAuthentication(OriginalSessionAuthentication):
    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this problem:

For that there are two ways of authentication in drf [see drf auth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

BasicAuthentication

SessionAuthentication (default)

SessionAuthentication has a forced csrf check, but BasicAuthentication doesn't. 
So my way is using BasicAuthentication in my view instead of SessionAuthentication.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication

class UserLogin(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to just make the enforce_csrf check do nothing:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class UnsafeSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Bypass the CSRF checks altogether
        '''
        pass
```

Otherwise you'll possibly end up with issues in the future if the upstream authenticate() method changes.  Also, it's MUCH simpler to just make the check not do anything :-)