# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted with csrf_exempt

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to receive a post request in my view from another site but I'm receiving this error in my view:

```
Forbidden <span>(403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

    Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.
```

This is my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
@requires_csrf_token
def notificacao(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notification_code = request.POST['notificationCode']
        if notification_code:
            url = 'https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' + notification_code + '?email=filipe.ferminiano@gmail.com' + '&token=token'
            r = requests.get(url)
            print r['status']
            if r['status']:
                b = teste(name = r['status'])
            else:
                b = teste(name = 'teste errado')
            b.save()
            print 'r ' + r
            return render(request, 'obrigado.html',{'code':notification_code})

        else:
            print 'notification code is null'
            b = teste(name = 'sem notification code')
            b.save()
            return render(request,'obrigado.html')
    else:
        b = teste(name = 'sem metodo post')
        b.save()
        return render(request, 'obrigado.html')
```

I already checked the documentation and added csrf_exempt and requires_csrf_token

Comment: That's strange... not sure what would be happening. Note that adding `@requires_csrf_token` shouldn't help -- that's intended for pages sending CSRF-token-validated requests, not pages receiving non-CSRF-validated requests (though shouldn't be any consequences from including it).

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17424074/1114) suggests that this issue could be caused by using the Django REST Framework, with it's `SessionBackend` enforcing CSRF tokens even if your views say they're not required. Are you also using Django REST Framework?

Comment: @JeremyBanks i'm not using the REST Framework

Comment: Did you add `{% csrf_token %}` into the form in the template ? `<form id=...>{% csrf_token %}` like they say in [Django Cross Site Request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) in the point `2.`

Comment: @Liarez I'm not using any form in my template. I just receive data from another side as a POST request.

Comment: Where is the other side ? Is in the same host ? Could you edit the POST you're receiving ? Could you generate a csrf token in the place that sends you the POST ?

Comment: The other side is controlled by a payment service. It's working now.  I just added an empty form with csrf_token tag.